# Firebase Cloud Messaging causes java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE of type I

Tags: android, google-play-services, firebase-cloud-messaging

I enabled FCM in my project, but get following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.app, PID: 28654
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No field GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_VERSION_CODE of type I in class Lcom/google/android/gms/common/zzc; or its superclasses (declaration of 'com.google.android.gms.common.zzc' appears in /data/app/com.example.app-2/base.apk:classes40.dex)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.example.app.location.MyLocationManager.<init>(MyLocationManager.java:39)
```

In my gradle files, I have:

```
provided "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.6"
```

and in one of its libraries:

```
compile libraries.firebase.messaging
```

And in my dependencies.gradle:

```
libraries = [ 
  firebase : [
     crash    : "com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:$versions.google.play.services",
     messaging: "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$versions.google.play.services"
  ],
]
```

And at MyLocationManager.java at that line I have:

```
GoogleApiClient apiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
```

**So whats the issue here?**

Comment: please post your gradle files

Comment: @phpdroid SInce it is too long, I posted Firebase relevant lines only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `compile libraries.firebase.messaging`
by `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.2.0'`
and make sure to use same version i.e `11.2.0` for every google service.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not changed anything. I forgot to mention the dependencies.gradle, so I think compile libraries.firebase.messaging is fine so far. One thing, the library was not compilable with google services 11.2.0, so I set it back to 10.2.6 and also my app to 10.2.6