# My App crashes when receive Firebase notification giving E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Firebase-FirebaseMessagingService Error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have app that I uploaded to google play store some days ago. but now it just misbehaving as it is not receiving any notification from firebase. I checked the firebase function log but in the log, it shows that notification sent successfully but not received on the device. Instead, the app crashes and stop working. First, I thought that there may be some error in code so I tested cloud message directly from firebase but it suddenly stopped app and app crashed. What could be the error and how to solve this?? Here is my Gradle app level.

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0"
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.theartofdev.edmodo:android-image-cropper:2.7.+'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
implementation 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:4.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1' //upgraded
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

and here is a project level

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Firebase Messaging Service Class

```
public class FirebaseMessagingService extends com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService {
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

    String notification_title=remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
    String notification_body=remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
    String clickAction=remoteMessage.getNotification().getClickAction();
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
        Intent intent=new Intent(clickAction);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        String CHANNEL_ID="MYCHANNEL";
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel=new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,"name",NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_LOW);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        Notification notification=new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext(),CHANNEL_ID)
                .setContentText(notification_body)
                .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        notificationManager.notify(1,notification);
    }
    else {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder=new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(notification_title)
                .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS| Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                .setContentText(notification_body);
        Intent intent=new Intent(clickAction);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent= PendingIntent.getActivity(
                this,
                1,
                intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        );
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        //set id for notification
        int mNotificationid=(int) System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Gets an instance of Notification Manager Service
        NotificationManager notificationManager=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //Build notification and issue it
        notificationManager.notify(mNotificationid,builder.build());


    }
```

[image]

Comment: Please someone help me.

Comment: Please post your FirebaseMessagingService code.

Comment: I belive that Firebase Messaging Service class has no issue as it is working fine before and i have not changed anything in that class. There is some problem from firebase cloud messaging side. Although i attach my Firebase Messaging Service code as well.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45877072/firebase-cloud-messaging-causes-java-lang-nosuchfielderror-no-field-google-play

Comment: I have tried but it doesn't solve my problem